# When Email was sent to email@xyz.com but it said it was from service@paypal need to resolve

Tags: magento2, email

I created an account on Magento for a new employee `Sam`, And a notification email was sent to `email@xyz.com`, But it said it was from `service@paypal.com`

I tried to check logs worked fine on the dev server.

I am using SMTP send-grid, anything that can be fixed?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please search `service@paypal` this email address into Database. May be it store in `core_config_data` table.

If you found it replace with your correct email address.

Comment: i looked into core_config_data i can't find such entry in it.
Even when i send custom email through code with hardcoded FROM.
i attached an image as well.